# using text files to save data iPhone sdk?

Tags: sql, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4, core-data

HI, 
Will it be okay to use text files instead of core data or sql? I simply don't understand SQL and core data.

thanks, 
TC

Answer (score 0):

Text files works, I will say that it depends on what you want to store and how you will use it when read back in.

Comment: I want to use it for storing string of radio title and their URL

Comment: @Tushar: I can't say exactly when you should/not should use text files but from what you are saying you shall do, there would be ok to do so.